# Disable child element iontabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

All hi, I use IonTabs plug-in (https://github.com/IonDen/ion.tabs), but I don't understand how to disable by means of JQuery one tab on an example , and remaining that worked? thanks for the help

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This answer:

    $( ".selector" ).tabs( { disabled: [1, 2] } );
Thanks for all ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the `id` of button, which you want to disable,
and add a css `pointer-events: none;`.
for example `disabledMe` is id of button, which you want to disable,

By CSS:

```
    #disabledMe{
        pointer-events:none;
    }
```

Or by JS:

```
    $('#disabledMe').css('pointer-events', 'none');
```